# Update package.json to reflect installed packages

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

Let's say my `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "cool_project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

And then after running `npm install` the version of `rxjs` version is `6.6.0`.

```sh
npm ls rxjs
`-- rxjs@6.6.0
```

Is there an `npm` or `yarn` command I can now run to pin the version inside my `package.json` to the version installed?

```json
{
  "name": "cool_project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "6.6.0"
  }
}
```

This is useful for me because if I want to check what package versions I'm on, I can easily see it directly inside of `package.json` and commit it to my git repo history.

Answer (score -1):

1) Change every version in package.json to *

2) run npm install --save-exact