# Update package.json for exact versions of installed node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, package.json

I want to lock all versions in package.json, but when I change a version from "^X.Y.Z" to "X.Y.Z" and install packages again, some features break because of older versions. I want to retrieve all versions of installed packages with ^X.Y.X.

**Is there a way to update the package.json file for the installed node_modules.**

There is a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590280/update-package-json-to-reflect-installed-packages) but can't find a helpful answer.

**Update**

I'm just currious if their is a utility library to do that labor work for me because in case of huge dependencies list I have to do npm view  version for each pkg and then update the obtained version in package.json.

Comment: You can only change "^X.Y.Z" to "X.Y.Z" in your package.json, not in the package.json of your dependencies.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Please take a look at the updated question

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't have package-lock.json? It serves exact the purpose you asks for and even more: it also locks versions of transient dependencies(dependencies of dependencies) which you'll never achieve with editing package.json

Comment: Ok Thanks let me try with that

Comment: Finally I got to the point https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924601/7344164

Comment: @skyboyer Thanks for your help!